# Windows Form start on boot with admin privileges (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, winforms, boot, administrator

I have a c# Windows Form program which require administrator privileges. I want it to automatically start when Windows boots (or when user log in).

I set the admin priviledge using the manifest file and adding in it :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

In order to start the program, I've added to Registry :

```
RegistryKey Key = 
    Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
Key.SetValue("My Program", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
```

This works well, as I can see in the task Manager, it is there with other programs. But when rebooting the device, nothing happens.

As BugFinder suggest, I tried to use the schedule task but it doesn't seems to work either. I cannot understand why this admin right is blocking everything.

Here is the schedule task code

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
   // Create a new task definition and assign properties
   TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
   td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Start BeOnePrgram";

   // Create a trigger that will fire after the system boot
   td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger());

   // Create an action that will launch BeOne whenever the trigger fires
   td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("BeOne", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString(), null));

   // Register the task in the root folder
   ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"DarkAutomatorTask", td);
```

Comment: `"\""` and `"\""` are not needed, use just `Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()`

Comment: Do you see the correct entry in your registry value?

Comment: @BugFinder, yes I see the correct entry in the registry

Comment: @codroipo I'm gonna try it without the backslash

Comment: If you want it on login, you could setup up a sheduled task

Comment: @BugFinder I've tried with the scheduled task, but it seems to not work too

Comment: Then that does seem odd. Its almost like the days when sysadmins first turned off any jobs that required desktop interaction.